# Wait for specific key-value pair to change in HTTP response?

Tags: flutter, http, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm building a mobile application with Flutter and using Firebase(firestore) to store data. When a user creates an account, I need to make POST request to an external website using that websites api, which will then return me a response that tells me if the user info is still registering (i.e. either provisioning or operational). Once it is operational, I will then get that data and store it in the users account information on firestore. However, it may take some up to 10 minutes for that information to be in the operational status. Can I use "retry" to repeatedly fetch this resource and check if the status has changed?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Timer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-async/Timer-class.html) to make that request periodically and check for status.

```
import 'dart:async';
main() {
  const timeout = const Duration(seconds: 10);
  new Timer.periodic(timeout, (Timer t) {...});
  // Run your API request and logic here ^ 
}
```

If the response is as expected, just [cancel](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-async/Timer/cancel.html) the Timer and proceed with your application flow.

Comment: What would happen if the app is closed though? Would this still be running in the background?